# Set up git to require a ssh keyfile

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, vps

I followed [the guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps#) to create a git repository for my website (Not using github or anything). The problem is i'm able to ssh and push to the repo without even requiring a keyfile.

I'm using SourceTree and all I did was set the source path to `ssh://user@mydomain.com/var/repo/site.git` and I can update my website without any key or passphrase at all.

How can I make my site's git require some authentication? The server I have is an Ubuntu LAMP server.

Comment: The key is the same key used for SSH. Can you SSH the server without a key or password? Is it possible that you already stored your public key in the server in the past for SSHing it?

Comment: It's not possible for me to ssh into the server without my passkey when i'm doing it from command prompt, but when I ssh through SourceTree I never put my passkey in there and it still connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run `ssh user@mydomain.com` to see if there's any authentication required. If there isn't, chances are there's an SSH key which it's picking up from `.ssh/config` such as `id_rsa` or `id_dsa` and at some point you put the corresponding public key on the remote server in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you want to have a password, either remove that key (and then fallback to the standard user/password prompt) or set up your SSH key to require a passphrase. (When you set up a passphrase, `ssh-agent` may cache your password for some length of time between asking you.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Following what you said I found the problem, check out my answer.

Comment: The correct way to mark an answer as correct is to select the answer that is correct, not append exactly the same answer to your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The answer I wrote is the answer to my question.

Comment: Right, but the point is the answer was given to you by the answer I gave. It's bad form to answer your own question, especially when someone else gave you the solution to look for in the first place.

Comment: Ah I got you. This is weird because it's like a 2 layered question and answer. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem is: It was in fact using my keyfile all along. Somehow it automagically associated my .ppk file that was on my desktop with that repository.

By simply renaming my keyfile on my desktop it would no longer let me ssh into my server. There is no settings or configuration to change this file path in SourceTree. I honestly have no idea how it did that.

[image: SourceTree]